# How to get a list of all dms discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am experimenting with discord.py and I can't find out how to get a list of all the DM channels the bot is in! I basicly need a list of either channel objects or channel ids of all DMs.

I have tried:

```
bot.get_private_channels()
bot.get_channels()
bot.get_dms()
bot.channels
```

and I have looked all over the internet for an answer, but I can't find anything.

Is this even possible in discord.py?

I really appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, but an alternative could be to look through all the members of all the guilds your bot is in, and check if [member.dm_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.dm_channel) is not None, if it is not None, it means there is a dm channel that was created between the bot and the member

Comment: I think this would work but when I try to loop through the members of each guild it only returns the bot. Something to do with intents but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: To fix the intents, check out this page https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Feel free to edit your question to add what you coded so far in case you still need help